# Misleading information from Review Links on top bar

Tags: bug, review-page

Today I saw a strange thing, on the top bar before the **Review** there is the number `3` (total post awaiting review)  with orange color (which I understand is 3 items in the review queue) but when I click on it all the queues showed `0` posts.

I cross the 10K mark yesterday and today I saw this behavior.

Is it a bug? Or are there another queue which I have to visit and fix it?

See the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number indicates how many review tasks the site has, which could be a good thing. Unfortunately the counter doesn't take into account that you already have reviewed the closed review queue, since it requires five close votes to put a question on hold. From a UX perspective this is a very bad behaviour, but none have solved the issue yet. If you want to, you could post this question on meta also (https://meta.stackexchange.com/) and see what response you get there.

Answer (score 1):

I see this all the time. There is no other queue that I know of.

What I think (and have come to peace with) is that the number is cached and that the cache sometimes is not reset when items are reviewed in the queue.

Interesting that it starts when you hit 10'! Maybee it is one of the queues that has this problem, or that a different cache mechanism is used when you have a certain amount of queues.